# How to put decimal point in UITextfield and should not be removed

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, string-formatting

In my project, we have the requirement where user need to enter amount in text field and text field should have 0.00 initially and as user keep entering values. The number should move from right to left and decimal point should always be there.
Like if user enter 1, it should be 0.01, if user enter 112 , it should display as 1.12 .

I am able to apply comma on text box field, But I am really stuck with decimal point requirement. I am not able to put decimal point for always in text box. Can someone please help me in this?

```
- (BOOL)textInput:(id <UITextInput>)textInput shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)string {

      UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)textInput;

    if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0)
    {
        return NO; // return NO to not change text
    }
    if (([string isEqualToString:@"0"] || [string isEqualToString:@""]) && [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location < range.location) {
        return YES;
    }

    // First check whether the replacement string's numeric...
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    bool isNumeric = [string isEqualToString:filtered];

    // Then if the replacement string's numeric, or if it's
    // a backspace, or if it's a decimal point and the text
    // field doesn't already contain a decimal point,
    // reformat the new complete number using
    // NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle
    if (isNumeric ||
        [string isEqualToString:@""] ||
        ([string isEqualToString:@"."] &&
         [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)) {

            // Create the decimal style formatter
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            [formatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
            [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

            // Combine the new text with the old; then remove any
            // commas from the textField before formatting
            NSString *combinedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            NSString *numberWithoutCommas = [combinedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
            NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:numberWithoutCommas];

            NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

            // If the last entry was a decimal or a zero after a decimal,
            // re-add it here because the formatter will naturally remove
            // it.
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"."] &&
                range.location == textField.text.length) {
                formattedString = [formattedString stringByAppendingString:@"."];
            }

            textField.text = formattedString;

        }

    // Return no, because either the replacement string is not
    // valid or it is and the textfield has already been updated
    // accordingly
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: Show what you tried, and where you stuck at ? Show the delegate methods

Comment: Please find the code i am using to updatee UItextfield

Comment: Your function always returns NO -- is that what you want?

Comment: Returning `NO` is appropriate because he updates `textField.text` himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: demo]

Here's a different approach. Don't implement the delegate method `textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:withString:`. Instead, connect the “Editing Changed” event of the text field to an action in your view controller. In the action, we'll do two things: reformat the text according to your requirements, and preserve the cursor position across the reformatting. Before the reformatting, we compute the offset from the end of the text back to the cursor position. After the reformatting, we reset the cursor position based on that offset:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldEditingChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
    int offset = [textField offsetFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument toPosition:textField.selectedTextRange.end];

    textField.text = textField.text.Nitya_reformattedString;

    UITextPosition *position = [textField positionFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument offset:offset];
    textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:position toPosition:position];
}
```

To initialize the text field, we can reformat the empty string:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.text = @"".Nitya_reformattedString;
}
```

To do the reformatting, we write a category on `NSString`:

```
@interface NSString (Nitya)
- (NSString *)Nitya_reformattedString;
- (BOOL)Nitya_isDigit;
@end

@implementation NSString (Nitya)

- (NSString *)Nitya_reformattedString {
```

Keep in mind that the text field sends “Editing Changed” **after** it has updated its text, so the text might contain non-digit characters or in fact contain anything, because the user could have selected the entire contents and pasted some other string over it. So step one is to throw away all non-digit characters:

```
    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (substring.Nitya_isDigit) {
            [newString appendString:substring];
        }
    }];
```

Note that we've also stripped out the decimal point.

Now let's define some constants that describe the desired format:

```
    static const int requiredFractionalDigitCount = 2;
    static const int requiredIntegerDigitCount = 1;
    static const int requiredDigitCount = requiredFractionalDigitCount + requiredIntegerDigitCount;
    static const int maxDigitCount = 12;
```

Step two is to trim characters off the front of the string if it has too many digits:

```
    if (newString.length > maxDigitCount) {
        [newString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length - maxDigitCount) withString:@""];
    }
```

We also want to trim leading zeros from the string (or else the zeros from the initial “0.00” string will stick around and look weird):

```
    while (newString.length > 0 && [newString characterAtIndex:0] == '0') {
        [newString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
    }
```

Now we want to make sure we have enough digits, by putting zeroes back on the front as necessary:

```
    while (newString.length < requiredDigitCount) {
        [newString insertString:@"0" atIndex:0];
    }
```

Finally, we put the decimal point back in:

```
    [newString insertString:@"." atIndex:newString.length - requiredFractionalDigitCount];
    return newString;
}
```

Here's the helper method `Nitya_isDigit`:

```
- (BOOL)Nitya_isDigit {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSCharacterSet *digits;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        digits = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    });

    return self.length == 1 && [digits characterIsMember:[self characterAtIndex:0]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used Nitya_reformatted string method and use my own code so that  my requirements fits in completely

Answer (score 0):

You can put the textfield text alignment to right to get text from right to left.

And to format the text according to your need, you can simply do this:

Initially set the textfield text to 0.00

```
 #pragma text field delegate methods
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

 if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"0.00"]) {
        textField.text=@"";
    }
    _enteredString=_textField.text;
    _textFieldString=[_enteredString stringByAppendingString:string];
    _yourLabel.text=[self formatNumber:_textFieldString];
    // you have to format this _yourLabel.text to fit into the textfield in your required format
    // Else if you dont want to do additional stuff, simply put the label on top of the textfield.
    return YES;
}

-(NSString *)formatNumber:(NSString *) enteredCharacter{

    float enteredValue=[enteredCharacter floatValue]*0.01;
   NSNumber *enteredNum=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:enteredValue];
    return [enteredNum stringValue];
}
```

**Note**: Make sure you enter only numbers in the textfield.